# Why does this branching question not work in MIPS when using doubles?

Tags: assembly, mips

I think its something to do with doubles but I can't find anything online that specifically tells me what is up

I am dividing by 999 and if the result is greater than 1 then I know the user has entered four digits and so I can continue with the code.
If the value is less than 1 or equal it should branch back up to main:

```
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------# 

# TASK C: INPUT ANY FOUR DIGIT NUMBER INTO THE PROGRAMME THEN DIVIDE BY 3.3   # 

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------# 


.data
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter your 4 digit number: " 
divisor1: .double 999
divisor: .double 3.3
answer1: .asciiz " divided by 3.3 that is ..."
test: .double 1.0




.text
    main:
    #prompt for 4 numbers numbers
        la $a0, prompt1    # Load and print string asking for string 

    li $v0, 4 

    syscall  

    # read in the user's number  

    li $v0, 7 #tells system to expect integer 

    syscall 

    #store user number $f0 where it has been read in 

    #mov.d $f1, $f0 

    mov.d $f2, $f0


    #is the number 4 digits? 
    # is fourdigits/999 > 1 if so then user has entered four digits 

    #load divisor into ¢f2

    ldc1 $f4, divisor1

    #store divided number in $f6

    div.d $f6, $f2,$f4



    # now we test if its  (fourdigits/999) > 1



    ldc1 $f8, test

    blt $f6, $f8, main #if $f6 is less then $f8 = 1 then ask for input again
```

Here's what it looks like if I put in 1234 when i remove the ble line

[image: example with the ble line removed]

```
As you can see all the requisite values are in there as doubles
```

Now if i add the ble I get this error.

[image: with the ble line]

> Error in /Applications/MipsAsses/logic2.asm line 59 column 6: "$f6":
>   operand is of incorrect type

Can you explain what is wrong here in simple terms. I am newish to mips and don't know the more complex stuff.

Comment: The error message is quite clear. Have you consulted an instruction set reference? `ble` takes integer operands, not floats. You want `c.le.s` and `bc1t`

Answer (score 1):

So I was sort of right, there's separate comparators for different types. I found the answer thanks to helpful comment and looking [here](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node20.html)

```
ldc1 $f8, test

    c.le.d $f6, $f8


    bc1t main  #if the coprocessor condition flag is set to true then the value is less than 1000 meaning it isnt 4 digits
```